# How to associate valgrind with a running process?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a binary called "ifmFuseHandler" which is invoked by a shell-script something like this: 
    `su - $USER -c "cd $DIR_INDEX;valgrind --leak-check=full ifmFuseHandler $IFM_SINGLE_THREAD -o allow_other $IFM_MOUNT"`

But the problem is, i can see the valgrind logs only once, when the control hits this line of shell, and post that even though the ifmFuseHandler is up and running, valgrind does not provide any profiling info.

So, as you can see below, but no further logging:

```
insite1@POC-Messaging1:/opt/insiteone/log> ps -ef | grep ifmFuseHandler
insite1    622     1  0 04:19 ?        00:00:02 valgrind --leak-check=full ifmFuseHandler -o allow_other /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount
insite1   3225 26014  0 04:32 pts/2    00:00:00 grep ifmFuseHandler
```

Comment: what does it log once?

Comment: @BЈовић: When the control reaches the shell script to invoke the fuseHandler, first time, it invokes it.

Comment: I just reread your Question, Are you wanting to do profiling or leak checking ?

Comment: @NWS: leak checking is a kind of memory profiling, any additional profiling apart from leaks i will do once i can make this work.

Comment: I was just checking you were using the right valgrind tool : memcheck for memory leaks is the default which you are using. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your shell-script to explicitly log the output of valgrind to a file as described [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.comment).

If your program is invoked multiple times, try using a filename with the PID, as described in the usage of `--log-file=<filename>` [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.basicopts).

Just make sure your output file is in an easily readable location.

Comment: I tried giving a filename too, but it logs only once. I haven't given a pid though